# Improve solrCloud search : two architectures

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I know solr search is I/O bound, if I have 4 node cluster and have an index separated into 4 blocks, which architecture below will have a better search performance :

1) Have 4 solr instances running in ONE single node and put each block of index over these 4 solr instances
2) Have a solr instances running in each node, hence total of 4-node cluster, and put each block of index into each solr instance.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd option will probably better and I explain.

Solr cores is a java program that contains few cache objects. When you put 4 Solr cores on the same node, they will use the same JVM RAM and the same CPU.

In the 1st oprion, the same JVM will need run 4 Solr cores and to collect the garbage of 4 cores instead of 1.

When you use 4 different nodes (4 JVMs) you will probably get better performance even if you host the 4 nodes on the same physical machine.